# error from pgflibraryfadings when adding tcolorbox with new tex4ht tikz driver. TL 2019

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, tex4ht

Just installed fresh TL 2019. I was trying the new tikz driver for tex4ht. I found this error. Here is a MWE. This error only shows up in `tex4ht` and not in `lualatex` and it shows up only when adding `tcolorbox` package

I actually do not use `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}` much any more. This was in an old file. So I can remove this package for now. But thought to mention this error just in case it affects other code somewhere else.

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}    

\ifdefined\HCode %This driver to tex4ht only. For tikz
   \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi     
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx,tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{adjustbox}    
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} %adding this causes the error
%\tcbuselibrary{listings}     
\begin{document}

\adjustbox{max width=1.35in}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\coordinate[label =above:$0$,   label =below:{$u=0$}] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label =above:$\pi$, label =below:{$u_x=0$}] (B) at (4,0);

\draw (A) -- node[above] {$u_t = k u_{xx} +c^2 u_x $}  node[below] {$f(x)$} ++ (B);
\end{tikzpicture} 
}    
\end{document}
```

Here is the command to reproduce

```
make4ht -ulm default foo2.tex
Output dir:
Compiler:       dvilualatex
Latex options:   -jobname=foo2
tex4ht.sty :    xhtml,,charset=utf-8
tex4ht   -cmozhtf -utf8
build_file      foo2.mk4
Output format   html5
Cannot open config file foo2.mk4
setting param correct_exit
setting param correct_exit
setting param correct_exit
setting param ext
Adding:         ext     dvi
LaTeX call: dvilualatex  -jobname=foo2  '\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode xhtml,,charset=utf-8,html5.a.b.c.\input "\detokenize{foo2.tex}"'
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019)
 restricted system commands enabled.
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.098 seconds
(./foo2.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/usepackage.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/usepackage.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/webquiz/pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvips.de
f
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
ostscript.def))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/usepackage.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.
tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikz-dependency/tikz-dependency.s
ty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/usepackage.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarybackgrounds.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarypatterns.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibrarypattern
s.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryfit.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryshapes.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibrary
shapes.geometric.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryshapes.misc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibrary
shapes.misc.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibrary
shapes.symbols.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryshapes.arrows.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibrary
shapes.arrows.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibrary
shapes.callouts.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibrary
shapes.multipart.code.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-dvips.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbraster.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbraster.code.tex' version '4.20'
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbskins.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskins.code.tex' version '4.20'
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/usepackage.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex' version '4.20'
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbbreakable.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbbreakable.code.tex' version '4.20'
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbhooks.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbhooks.code.tex' version '4.20'
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbtheorems.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbtheorems.code.tex' version '4.20'
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbfitting.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbfitting.code.tex' version '4.20'
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbxparse.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbxparse.code.tex' version '4.20'
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/usepackage.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3dvips.def))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcblistingsutf8.code.te
x
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistingsutf8.code.tex' version '4.20'
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/listingsutf8.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/stringenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdfescape.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcblistings.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistings.code.tex' version '4.20'

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcblistingscore.code.te
x
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistingscore.code.tex' version '4.20'
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbprocessing.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbprocessing.code.tex' version '4.20'
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty)))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbexternal.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbexternal.code.tex' version '4.20'
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbmagazine.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbmagazine.code.tex' version '4.20'
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbvignette.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbvignette.code.tex' version '4.20'

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryfadings.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfadings
.code.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
\a:tikzpicture ->\Picture
                          *{}
l.31 ...ing{east}{\pgfuseshading{pgf@lib@fade@east}}
                                                  %
?
```

Using TL 2019 on linux

```
which make4ht
/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/make4ht
which lualatex
/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/lualatex
```

Comment: My guess is that it has to do with the changed shading code which makes them no longer global.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It compiles correctly with the current version of the `pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def` driver:

```
% Copyright 2006 by Till Tantau
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.
%
% See the file doc/generic/pgf/licenses/LICENSE for more details.


% Driver commands for tex4ht

%
% Load common pdf commands:
%
  %\input pgfsys-dvisvgm.def
  \input pgfsys-dvips.def

%
% tex4ht-specific stuff:
%

\newcount\pgf@sys@svg@picnum

\AtBeginDocument{
  % configure the output picture format to svg
  \Configure{Picture}{.svg}
  % insert tex4ht hook to the code used at the start and end of each TikZ picture
  \def\pgfsys@beginpicture{%
    \bgroup%
    \ifdefined\inside@pict@cmd% handle nested uses
    \def\run@pict@cmd{}% insert the \Picture hooks only in the top nesting level
    \def\end@pict@cmd{}%
    \else
    % use different version of \Picture depending on the vertical mode
    \ifvmode\def\run@pict@cmd{\Picture*}\else\def\run@pict@cmd{\Picture+}\fi%
    \def\end@pict@cmd{\EndPicture}%
    \fi%
    % command used to detect nesting
    \def\inside@pict@cmd{}%
    \csname a:tikzpicture\endcsname%
    \orig@pgfsys@begin%
  }%
  \def\pgfsys@endpicture{%
    \orig@pgfsys@end%
      \csname b:tikzpicture\endcsname%
      \egroup%
      \par%
  }%
}


% Make the code inserted by tex4ht configurable

\NewConfigure{tikzpicture}{2}
\Configure{tikzpicture}{%
  % \ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP%\HtmlParOff
  \protect\csname nested:math\endcsname% support display math
  \ifdefined\Picture\run@pict@cmd\fi
}{\ifdefined\EndPicture\end@pict@cmd\fi}

\let\orig@pgfsys@begin\pgfsys@beginpicture
\let\orig@pgfsys@end\pgfsys@endpicture
\def\pgf@sys@postscript@header#1{{\special{! #1}}}


\endinput


%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% End:
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure what `with the current version of the pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def` means because I just installed TL 2019? What exactly do I need to make it work then? I just did update for TL 2019 and it say no update exist. So it is not clear to me what I should do to make this error go away? I am assuming your driver is included in TL 2019 and it does not require separate download from another web site.

Comment: @Nasser no, it is not included in TeX Live, I've contacted TikZ people to include it in TikZ directly, but it may take some time

Comment: I see. Now I understand. So you meant it is changed in source control and it is not in TL to update yet. No problem, I will wait and try update later then. Thanks.

Comment: @michal.h21 “I've contacted TikZ people to include it in TikZ directly” I have never received this message from you.

Comment: @HenriMenke sorry, I thought I did. I don't remember it exactly. Anyway, the most recent variant of the TeX4ht Dvisvgm driver is here: https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht

Comment: @michal.h21 Please open a pull request at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/pulls

Comment: @HenriMenke do you think it is better to completely replace the old TikZ driver for TeX4ht, or to add it as an alternative?

Comment: @michal.h21 What is actually the difference between the two?  I'm happy to make yours the default but we should keep the current one around.

Comment: @HenriMenke It uses Dvisvgm for the actual conversion, so it keeps all font information and formatting.

Comment: @michal.h21 I've used `git filter-branch` to extra only `pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def` from the repo and put it in the correct directory while preserving the file history.  Then I merged it into PGF/TikZ master.  Please review https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/pull/836